# How to link a button to an action in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to create a button, that when it receives the "Touch Up Inside" call, will ring a phone number. However, the action I have declared in my ViewController.h is not showing up in my Connections Inspector, so I cannot connect the code to my button. Within my ViewController.h I have written the line of code:

```
-(IBAction)makePhoneCall(id)sender;
```

And I have finished my declaration in my ViewController.m, but it still wont appear in my Connections Inspector.

Any suggestions for help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does other custom entries (like outlets, other actions) show properly?

Comment: Have you set the correct custom class in the identity inspector?

Comment: I havnt added any other outlets or actions and also I havnt set any kind of class in the identity inspector, what should this be set to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to go to your storyboard, click on the Utilities button on the far right.

From there click on your controller; third tab from left you will see "Custom Class", there you need to change the name to the name of the class in which you declare your method.

See picture:

[image]

From then on, try to connect your method again using connection inspector.

Edit:

Adding picture for selecting the view controller in storyboard:

[image]

Comment: I have tried this, but after I type it in, it keeps correcting itself to "UIView"